# Is there a 'mathematical program' to separate P from BQP?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, complexity-classes, quantum-computing, open-problem

This question has been motivated by the existence of an ongoing (and possibly long-term) program for $P\neq NP$ conjecture like [GCT](https://doi.org/10.1145/1944345.1944346)(Mulmuley, 1999).

- Usually, such programs are marked by long and short-term goals. (see [Fortnow review article](https://dl.acm.org/doi/pdf/10.1145/1562164.1562186))
- A 'decent' number of people recognise the program's viability.

> Is there a similar program for $P$ vs $BQP$ problem?

A natural (to think) approach is to search for quantum analogous to Adelman's theorem. [(see Aaronson's answer)](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/15066/68722). Informally, it is a search for 'pooling the quantumness trick'.

Are there any other relevant developments related to this problem?

Please note: this question is concerned with the existence of strategies to separate the classes rather than just looking for supporting evidence for $P\neq BQP$ as discussed [here](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/q/32817/68722).

Comment: If you showed P ≠ BQP, you would show P ≠ PSPACE. The only "program" I know for showing this is Mulmuley's, so it seems unlikely anybody has come up with a plausible program to show P ≠ BQP.

Comment: @PeterShor, point taken. // just curious to know the viability of an attempt to resolve P vs BQP using maths machinery/notions coming out of GCT. To be precise, a (quantum) analogues problem to permanent-determinant dichotomy. And then developing/implementing maths for it.